# cannot extend class component in react , everything else works fine

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, es6-class, react-component

*Cannot extend class component , everything else like arrow functions work just fine.*

I am creating a simple app which has some components.I have created some components as functions and it works well but when i am trying to create a component by extending a class it fails. I have tried many things but none seem to work for me . I am new to React .

**This is the code I am trying to run:**

```
import React,{ component } from 'react';
import CardList from './CardList';
import { robots } from './robots';
import SearchBox from './SearchBox';

class App extends component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        robots: robots,
        searchfield: ''
    }
}
    render(){
    return(
    <div className='tc'>
      <h1>RoboFriends</h1>
      <SearchBox />
      <CardList robots={this.state.robots} />
    </div>
    );
}
}

export default App;
```

**I get an error in the browser as follows:**

```
TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
Module../src/App.js
C:/Users/Aku/Desktop/robofriends/src/App.js:6
  3 | import { robots } from './robots';
  4 | import SearchBox from './SearchBox';
  5 | 
> 6 | class App extends component {
  7 |   constructor() {
  8 |       super();
  9 |       this.state = {
View compiled


__webpack_require__
C:/Users/Aku/Desktop/robofriends/webpack/bootstrap:784
  781 | };
  782 | 
  783 | // Execute the module function
> 784 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  785 | 
  786 | // Flag the module as loaded
  787 | module.l = true;
View compiled


fn
C:/Users/Aku/Desktop/robofriends/webpack/bootstrap:150
  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {
View compiled


Module../src/index.js
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:377:62
__webpack_require__
C:/Users/Aku/Desktop/robofriends/webpack/bootstrap:784
  781 | };
  782 | 
  783 | // Execute the module function
> 784 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  785 | 
  786 | // Flag the module as loaded
  787 | module.l = true;
View compiled


fn
C:/Users/Aku/Desktop/robofriends/webpack/bootstrap:150
  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {
View compiled


1
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:586:18
__webpack_require__
C:/Users/Aku/Desktop/robofriends/webpack/bootstrap:784
  781 | };
  782 | 
  783 | // Execute the module function
> 784 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  785 | 
  786 | // Flag the module as loaded
  787 | module.l = true;
View compiled


checkDeferredModules
C:/Users/Aku/Desktop/robofriends/webpack/bootstrap:45
  42 |  }
  43 |  if(fulfilled) {
  44 |      deferredModules.splice(i--, 1);
> 45 |      result = __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = deferredModule[0]);
     | ^  46 |  }
  47 | }
  48 | 
View compiled


Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push]
C:/Users/Aku/Desktop/robofriends/webpack/bootstrap:32
  29 |  deferredModules.push.apply(deferredModules, executeModules || []);
  30 | 
  31 |  // run deferred modules when all chunks ready
> 32 |  return checkDeferredModules();
     | ^  33 | };
  34 | function checkDeferredModules() {
  35 |  var result;
View compiled


(anonymous function)
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:1:75
This screen is visible only in development. It will not appear if the app crashes in production.
Open your browser’s developer console to further inspect this error.  Click the 'X' or hit ESC to                           
dismiss this message.
```

**NOTE: IT SHOWS COMPILED SUCCESSFULLY IN THE TERMINAL**
*I am new to React it will be a great help for me. Thanks*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo when you try to import `{component}` from react. It need to start with uppercase character

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react';
```

You can name default imports by any name you like but imports within `{}` need to use the exact same name and are called named imports

Comment: Thanks...It was a great help

Answer (score 0):

your Component class import is not correct. You need to import `Component` instead of `component`

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  ...
}
```